# Raw input and window interaction issues when RIDEV_NOLEGACY flag is provided

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm have a few issues related to usage of raw input devices registered with the RIDEV_NOLEGACY flag.

- when a window is inactivated and I set focus via mouse click to window, focus is obtained but the window z-order remains the same. (This doesn't happen while alt-tabbing)
- unable to interact with the window chrome(resizing, title bar buttons)

In my input class I create a thread which creates a message only window and registers raw input devices. In another thread I create a window which is used for OpenGL rendering.

Everything works fine until the no legacy flag is specified. Perhaps this is just my ignorance of the Windows API. I've tried working around the first issue by way of ::Set[Active,Foreground]Window hacks to no effect. Is there a proper way handle these issues or should I just avoid disabling legacy keyboard and mouse messages?

Comment: did you find any solution?
I didn't find your question when I asked mine, but I think its the same as mine http://stackoverflow.com/q/10185067/730223.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you register for raw input from a device you get that raw data whether your window is foreground or background. Another way to put that is: you get raw input from the device for ALL application windows. So, if you prevent legacy Windows messages from being generated, by using the RIDEV_NOLEGACY flag, you'll prevent legacy Windows messages from being generated for ALL Windows. Most Windows applications depend on those legacy messages in order to operate correctly. If your application is not a fullscreen application RIDEV_NOLEGACY is not a good idea to use.

Comment: To clarify, RIDEV_NOLEGACY only affects the application that is calling it, not all applications, obviously. But it is application-wide, so having one window which uses normal messages and another which only does raw input with RIDEV_NOLEGACY does not seem to possible. Just don't use RIDEV_NOLEGACY.

Comment: To further clarify, you may want to use RIDEV_NOLEGACY if you are creating a single window, full screen application, to prevent the input system from generating and dispatching Windows messages such as WM_KEYDOWN, WM_CHAR, WM_MOUSEMOVE etc. In this case you will use raw input to capture and respond to the keyboard/mouse state depending on your needs. This would be a performance benefit due to less task switching / kernel interrupts etc. It boils down to the ambiguous usage of the word 'legacy'.